# Advantages and disadvantages to claiming Canadian citizenship

Tags: canada, citizenship, dual-citizenship

I'm considering looking into whether I can claim Canadian citizenship because my father was born in Manitoba. (I was born in North Dakota, not very far from Manitoba.)

What would be the advantages and disadvantages? (I already know of one potential advantage or I wouldn't have asked the question: some job ads are addressed to Canadian citizens.)

Comment: It sounds like based on the information that you've given that you already received Canadian citizenship involuntarily at birth (unless your father lost Canadian citizenship before you were born).

Comment: What one person considers an advantage, others may consider a disadvantage, and each can change depending on a range of circumstances. As well, many have no relevance to or reliance on law, and those that do would be quite varied. This is a terrible question for so many reasons.

Comment: What other citizenship(s) do you have? Some countries will take away your citizenship if you apply for and receive a different one.

Comment: @gnasher729 : None besides those mentioned here.

Comment: @gnasher729: except that in this case the OP already has Canadian citizenship, and is just getting documentation of it, not getting a new citizenship